# Comparison of SDI frameworks

Tags: web-mapping, geoportal, geonode, spatial-data-infrastructure

What are the main differences between these SDI, especially in the level of geospatial features and ease of integration with existing CMS?

- [Cartaro](http://cartaro.org/)
- [Geonode](http://geonode.org/)
- [GeOrchestra](http://www.georchestra.org/en/index.html)
- [EasySDI](http://www.easysdi.org/)

I wonder for the reasons why SDI software is not so popular?

Comment: Geoportal for what need?

Comment: https://groups.drupal.org/node/89769

Comment: none of these SDI are listed here

Comment: I am sorry but your most recent edit has made the question even less clear. Try to avoid the use of the word "best" because it implies subjectivity, and instead spend more time on clarifying your requirements.

Comment: the question seems to be now very clear

Comment: One reason I can think of as to why they are not popular is that none of them are very mature. Another is that an SDI comprises all aspects of an organization's geospatial business and not many organizations seem willing to put all their eggs in one basket, or have custom solutions, or just don't need CMS integration.